Facing error while using datadog API to fetch metric timeseries
Request:
curl --location --globoff 'https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/query?from=1734615540&to=1734615600&query=avg%3Akafka.consumer_lag{environment%3Aproduction%2Cconsumer_group%3Amy-consumer-group%2C%20topic%3Amy_topic}' \
--header 'Accept: application/json'

Response:
{
    "status": "error",
    "res_type": "time_series",
    "resp_version": 1,
    "query": "avg:kafka.consumer_lag{environment:production,consumer_group:my-consumer-group, topic:my_topic}",
    "from_date": 1734615540000,
    "to_date": 1734615600000,
    "series": [],
    "values": [],
    "times": [],
    "error": "Invalid query input:\n",
    "group_by": []
}

Not sure what is wrong with the query syntax.

Tags and metric is appropriate.
from and to is appropriate
Even on datadog dashboard metric explorer same query is generated which i have used in the API.

Any help is appreciated.

The error response looks like it received the query as intended, but I am wondering if the un-encoded curly braces could be the problem nevertheless? Try and provide the fully URL-encoded version for the query parameter: avg%3Akafka.consumer_lag%7Benvironment%3Aproduction%2Cconsumer_group%3Amy-consumer-group%2Ctopic%3Amy_topic%7D

I am using postman to make the call. CURL request provided is from postman itself,
Getting a different error msg  after replacing { with %7B in postman.
Error parsing query: \nunable to parse avg:kafka.consumer_lag{environment:production,consumer_group:my-consumer-group, topic:my_topic{: Rule 'or_op' didn't match at '{' (line 1, column 95).


So your actual problem is not with cURL, but with postman? Then how exactly are you making that request in there?

@C3roe This just got resolved magically to my surprise , the actual issue was with the timestamp ( i was using future timestamp mistakenly [i assumed local time but the timestamp was in GMT which i just discovered]). Even the error message in the response denoted that query is invalid so i did not even care double check timestamp. Now when the GMT time passed - after an hour or so the response is what i desire. Thanks so much for the response.

A lesson to silly me on not always relying on what system tells you but sometimes checking basic facts.
